# Recurrence equation $f(g\cdot x)/f(x)=t$

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

I am trying to solve equation $\frac{f(g x)}{f(x)}=t$ and I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions? In my problem, $f$ is a continuous and weakly increasing function.

Comment: Is g or t a constant?

Comment: Yes, both are constants. In particular, $g \in (0,1)$ and $t > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\ln f(e^x)$. Then $f(gx)=tf(x)$ becomes $F(x+\ln g)=F(x)+\ln t$ with the simplest continuous solution $F(x)=F(0)+\frac{\ln t}{\ln g}x$, so
$$f(x)=e^{F(\ln x)}=C\cdot x^{\frac{\ln t}{\ln g}} $$

Comment: More precisely, that is _one_ solution (family of solutions). An infinity of other solutions can be found by adding something of period $\ln g$ to $F$, and as long as the "something" never decreases faster than a slope of $\frac{-\ln t}{\ln g}$, the resulting $f$ will still be weakly increasing.

Comment: This looks right, but since I'm not familiar with this type of problems, can you clarify how to get the solution to $F(x+\ln g)=F(x) + \ln t$?

Comment: @TomH "If I go $\ln g$ to the right, I go $\ln t$ up" really suggests a linear solution (until Henning Makholm comes along and adds his wiggly someting)